# Add a Fragment to Backstack of Navigation Graph

Tags: android, kotlin

I am using the UI Navigation Graph. I have fragment `A` and `B`. My application starts on Fragment `B` to show some information. Then the user can press back and end up in `A`. Then from `A` the user usually picks something and ends up in `B`.

Normally I can pop `B` from the stack and show `A`. However, when the app just launches there is no `A` in the back stack. I guess I could add `A` to the backstack manually but I wonder if the Navigation UI Graph has something that lets me do this.

I cannot change the order of my application fragments. That means that I still need to show `B` first.

Comment: Why does your application start on Fragment B if you want A on your back stack?

Comment: Good question. My application starts on Fragment `B` to show some information. This information is important and the order should not be changed.

Answer (score 1):

As per the [Principles of Navigation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-principles#fixed_start_destination), the start destination of your app should always be the last screen the user sees before they exit your app. That means that your Fragment `A` should be the start destination of your graph.

As per the [Conditional Navigation documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional), if you have important information that the user should see (such as a [first time user experience](https://developer.android.com/guide/navigation/navigation-conditional#first-time_user_experience)), you should have your Fragment `A` `navigate` to your Fragment `B`. This ensures that when you're on Fragment `B`, Fragment `A` is on the back stack already.

Comment: Unfortunately changing the problem is not possible for this question.

Comment: Can you explain why that's the case? Because as long as you `navigate()` to `B` in `onCreate()`, the user will never see `A` - from their perspective, they'll start on `B`